# Google Analytics on AJAX pages

Tags: ajax, google-analytics

I need to track visits of page that loads via Ajax. I'm currently using the latest HTML5 Boilerplate Google Analytics snippet (as of September 2017):

```
<script>
    window.ga=function(){ga.q.push(arguments)};ga.q=[];ga.l=+new Date;
    ga('create','UA-XXXXX-Y','auto');ga('send','pageview')
</script>
<script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" async defer></script>
```

For example, the page that I'm calling via Ajax shows as an overlay popup and does not update the URL in the address bar. It comes from a directory like this:

www.mysite.com/ajaxpages/popup.html

Do I need to place the entire Analytics snippet on the popup.html page? Do I have to update it? [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications) says I need to update my code to something like:

```
ga('set', 'page', '/new-page.html');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

It seems fairly simple but I'm not exactly sure how I need to update the tracking code I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to put the entire analytics snippet in the popup page. In the function that loads the Ajax popup locate the bit that checks for the ajax success event and paste your second snippet in there; this will set a page path (so every subsequent call will use the new url) and the pageview call will send the updated information.